# How to insert a list of rows into supabase from flutterflow?

Tags: list, arraylist, insert, supabase, flutterflow

I can insert a single row into supabase from flutterflow, but I need to insert a list of rows for example, If I want to insert 30 students attendance status (true or false) in attendance table in supabase using one request, how to do this process in flutterflow?

I tried to use supabase api or use flutterflow custom code but I couldn't complete the process.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.